# AngularJS textbox return undefined value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, undefined-behavior

When I press my button check in bootstrap modal, I want to print the value of my textbox in my console. But my textbox returns a undefined. It seems that all of the code are working perfect.

this is link [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/szVK5OaFhdyDQX0ozuq8?p=preview)

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
<head>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ><button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('lg')" >Large modal</button>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
    </div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="new" /><button ng-click="check()" >check</button>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your modal is set to have its own controller, and therefore its own scope,

when you execute the function 'check' it tries to alert $scope.new,

$scope.new isn't set on the modal scope.

one way to overcome this is to pass the new variable into the function, and let the function alert the passed value.

here's a fixed [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WGRCeMY5MiYlnVXjXMlY?p=preview)

when calling check(), pass in the new variable:

```
<button ng-click="check(new)">check</button>
```

and in your controller change check function:

```
$scope.check = function(text) {
   alert(text);
};
```